# Back wheel is still smoking after changing brakes. What could be causing this?

Tags: brakes

I noticed smoke coming from my back passenger wheel so I stopped and looked to find fluid all over the back of my van I came straight home the van felt like my brake was stuck and wheel was smoking really bad. My boyfriend thought it was the brake cylinder so I got one and new shoes for it. My boyfriend changed them out but it's still smoking and feels like the brake is on. Can you tell me if you think it might be the Emergency brake and if so can I bypass it long enough for me to get my next paycheck?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  What is the make, model and year of your vehicle?

Comment: Want to clarify as to if it is DRUM brakes, like it reads, or DISC brakes?

Comment: Hard to answer a very open question. Make, Model, Year please. Then the MV dwarves can go to work.